# Limit disk I/O one program creates?

Tags: linux, lvm, kvm-virtualization

Hardware: one virtualization server. Dual Nehalem, 24GB RAM, 2 TB mirrored HD.

Software: Debian, KVM, virt-manager on the server with several virtual machines that use Linux too. 2 TB Disk is a big LVM, each VM gets a logical volume and makes its own partitions in that.

Problem: One of the programs that runs on one of the VMs creates huge disk load. This never was an issue, because the program never ran on such a powerful hardware. Now the CPUs are fast, and lots of I/O is the result. We cant do much against that at the moment, because the tool is a black box. On the other hand, the speedy computation is welcome. The program creates about 5 GB of temp files which get overwritten during the next iteration.

Question: How can we limit the disk I/O for the process?

Comment: I don't know if you can limit the disk I/O, but it may help your server if you decrease the I/O prioroty of that process. If you use the CFQ scheduler, you can do that with ionice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `ionice` command. For idle priority (lowest priority):

`ionice -c3 bash`

You can use the regular `nice` command to slow down the CPU priority as well which maybe would limit IO as a side effect too.

You might be able to also limit the amount of FDs on the program with `ulimit`.  This might limit the max open files the application is capable of, but it also might just break it.

Yet another option might be to go buy a bunch more memory and map those temp files to a ram disk with mount, taking the load off of the disk entirely.  You could of course do the same by adding another disk for the temp files as well.

Comment: Sounds good. Working on it.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL6 will also support cgroups, which lets you do a finer grained tuning. You could try to look that up in Debian as well